# ProtectedData use a dictionary of strings

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, encryption, protected

I would use the ProtectedData I found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

My problem is that I can not understand how I can adapt a dictionary to a source of bytes, although it converts from a byte [] string, when I go to do the Unprotect, can not decrypt it. I have tried so:

code without DataProtection:

```
public static void SetLoginUserDataForFile(ConnectionData data)
{
    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> retVal = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
    Dictionary<string, string> dataValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    if (File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "PROGRAMFILE", "PROGRAMFILE")))
    {
        string fileData = File.ReadAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "PROGRAMFILE", "PROGRAMFILE"));
        try
        {
            retVal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>(Decrypt(fileData, "pa$$w0rd"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            retVal = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
        }

        dataValues.Add("HashedPwd", data.HashedPwd);
        dataValues.Add("CanAccessOffline", data.LoggedUser.CanAccessOffline.ToString());
        dataValues.Add("CanSavePassword", data.LoggedUser.CanSavePassword.ToString());

        if (retVal.ContainsKey(data.LoggedUser.UserName))
            retVal[data.LoggedUser.UserName] = dataValues;
        else
            retVal.Add(data.LoggedUser.UserName, dataValues);

        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "PROGRAMFILE", "PROGRAMFILE"), Encrypt(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(retVal), "pa$$w0rd"));
    }
}
```

i try this:

```
public static void SetLoginUserDataForFile(ConnectionData data)
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    String GuidID = assembly.GetType().GUID.ToString();

    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> retVal = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
    Dictionary<string, string> dataValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    if (File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "PROGRAMFILE", "PROGRAMFILE")))
    {
        string fileData = File.ReadAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "PROGRAMFILE", "PROGRAMFILE"));
        try
        {
            retVal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>(Decrypt(fileData, DataProtection.Unprotect(GetBytes(GuidID)).ToString()));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            retVal = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
        }

        dataValues.Add("HashedPwd", data.HashedPwd);
        dataValues.Add("CanAccessOffline", data.LoggedUser.CanAccessOffline.ToString());
        dataValues.Add("CanSavePassword", data.LoggedUser.CanSavePassword.ToString());

        if (retVal.ContainsKey(data.LoggedUser.UserName))
            retVal[data.LoggedUser.UserName] = dataValues;
        else
            retVal.Add(data.LoggedUser.UserName, dataValues);

        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "PROGRAMFILE", "PROGRAMFILE"), Encrypt(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(retVal), DataProtection.Protect(GetBytes(GuidID)).ToString()));
    }
}

public static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return bytes;
}
```

Once I read it again, by calling the file, no longer able to open it ... how do I fix?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you assume that your file is a text file and that byte arrays can be serialized and deserialized with a simple call to `ToString()`. That is not the case.

Use the methods of `File` that read and write byte arrays. Because that is what you have.

Comment: I know that you're right , I have to change the save structure.